# Scipy code to solve optimization problem ( gurobi code is written!)

Tags: optimization, gurobi, scipy-optimize-minimize

I wrote a Gorubi optimization code, but because of some issues, I need to convert to Scipy code. Still have difficulties to convert it. Here is a part of code related to Gorubi:

```
m = Model()
#x is charging, discharging variable
x = m.addVars(n,lb=-1.5,ub=1.5,vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="x")
#Y is SOC variable
Y = m.addVars(n+1,lb=0,ub=100,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="Y")
# Add constraint: SOC[start]=50, initial SOC
m.addConstr(Y[0]==initialsoc,name='c1')
#Final targeted SOC
m.addConstr(Y[n]>=65,name='c2')

m.addConstrs((Y[i+1]-Y[i] == 3.75*x[i] for i in range(n)), name='c0')
#Objective function. 6 comes from capacity of inverter.
obj1=sum(((load[i+1]-(6*x[i]))*(load[i+1]-(6*x[i])) for i in range (n)))

m.setObjective(obj1,GRB.MINIMIZE)
m.optimize()
```

My x constraint can only have -1 or 0 or 1 values. The other constraint is Y where at each step y(i+1)-y(i) equals to 3.75*X(i).
Is it possible to convert this code to Scipy? Or do you recommend any other libraries?

Comment: Scipy does not contain a MIP solver.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen   Thanks for the response. You are right, I figure it out too! I think my solution is MIP.